# Сделать заглавными первые буквы слов через цикл for

Tags: python

Пытался сделать, чтобы первые буквы слов были с большой буквы

```
s=input()
for i in s: 
   for b in i:
       if i[b] == chr(32):
       print(i[b+1].upper())
```

Но есть ошибка:  if i[b] == chr(32):
TypeError: string indices must be integers. Как можно решить ?

Comment: А.. что вы имеете в виду в этих двух циклах for, что обходите?

Comment: Честно говоря я уже запутался, но по сути я пытаюсь следующий символ после проблема сделать большим и вывести, но это не правильно. Т.к. надо вывести всю строку с заменой первых букв

Comment: В Вашем случае не нужно два цикла, достаточно одного. И на мой взгляд проще работать не со следующим символом, а с предыдущим, запоминая его в цикле. И сделать проверку, если предыдущий символ - разделитель, тогда выводить заглавную букву, иначе обычную

Comment: Тут дело в том, что у вас второй цикл `for b in i:` перебирает не индексы символов, а сами символы в строке. Если вам нужны именно индексы, тогда делаем простой перебор чисел через range. Но это просто ремарка, вам уже дали правильное решение.

Answer (score 5):

Если известно, что слова разделяются каким-то конкретным символом, например пробелом можно с помощью split()

```
text = input()
for word in text.split():
   print(word.capitalize())
```

Подробней о [split](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html)

Comment: используйте capitalize()

Comment: да, Вы правы, спасибо)

Comment: если разделитель - пробел, то почему не просто  `text.title()`  ?

Comment: так просто будет понятней, как именно нужно доработать, если придется менять список разделителей. К тому же в заголовке задачи стоит с помощью цикла